# I need a 3.3V relay that connects a Teensy 4.1 to 10 24V solenoid valves

Tags: relay, solenoid, teensy

I am in a school project. I need a relay that can connect a Teensy 4.1 to a 24 VDC solenoid.
We have around 10 solenoid valves and 4 transducers but the only thing to be considered right now are the solenoids. Hence I need at least a 16-channel relay.
The solenoid is rated at 10 W and its product code is D2013-V-VO-C204.

I believe the output pins of the Teensy are 3.3 V.
Also will the power relay require an external power source?

I am not very experienced in electronics so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide data sheet link to the solenoid. I'm looking for a link to a pdf document.

Comment: https://www.gemssensors.com/docs/default-source/resource-files/catalog-pages/catalog-j_d-series.pdf     I hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

10W at 24VDC is less than 500mA so just about any small mechanical relay will work (preferably with some coil suppression such as a TVS or a diode added). You would need a transistor to drive the relays and another diode to deal with the relay coil inductance.

You could also use a logic-level [MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7470pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355ff2fe11c18) directly. The diode shown deals with the energy stored in the solenoid inductance when the MOSFET turns off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1buJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>